# Configuring replication config file for Gerrit

Tags: gitlab, gerrit

My Gerrit **replication.config** looks like:

```
[remote "company-svc"]
projects = dev-portal-ui
url = git@gitlab.eng.company.com:/core-build/${name}.git
push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
```

I'm able to mirror clone using command:

```
cd ${GERRIT_SITE}/git
git clone --mirror ssh://git@gitlab.eng.company.com/core-build/dev-portal-ui.git
```

On Gitlab, I found ssh URL as:

```
git@gitlab.eng.company.com:core-build/dev-portal-ui.git
```

Is my configuration for **replication.config** is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

Both SSH URLs syntax are correct:

```
ssh://git@server/...
git@server:...
```

The first one is the [SSH URI scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04#section-3.3), the second one is a [scp-like syntax](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php).

Comment: Thanks! After changing [remote "company-svc"] to [remote "dev-portal-ui"] ... it worked ... not sure how and why...